# Non-computational models of cognition

Tags: cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling

There is a [question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8133/are-there-any-models-of-human-cognition-that-do-not-depend-on-physicalism-or-mat) on this site that asks a somewhat related question, whether there are non-physical models for cognition.  However, that question still assumes a computational paradigm for the non-physical cognition.

Another [question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/985/applications-of-computational-learning-theory-in-the-cognitive-sciences?rq=1) asks whether computational learning theory has been applied to cognitive science, which would then allow us to say what non-computational learning would look like.  However, there is only one answer that provides a non-computational alternative.

Are there any accepted models that do away with computationalism altogether?  Such a model would depend on cognition performing incomputable feats, such as being a Turing oracle, violating the No Free Lunch Theorem, or reducing NP to P.

Comment: I have the impression that  "non-computation" and "cognition" are antonyms...

Comment: @DenisCousineau, that is my general impression of the field.  I am curious if that is officially stated somewhere.

Comment: I am not aware of any specific citation. Neisser (1967) defined cognitive psychology as regarding all the processes by which inputs are transformed, reduced, enhanced, memorized and retrieved. So his view --at the origin of the information processing paradigm-- is clearly computational.

Comment: Here is an interesting article stating that splitting the brain does not split consciousness.  This would seem evidence the mind is not the brain.  http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/releases/315508.php

Comment: I've asked the question whether the split brain experiments prove the mind is not the brain, but it has been closed.  https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/does-the-split-brain-disprove-a-materialistic-mind